# Why is Excel not doing math properly?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried this very simple formula:

`=+(-(1/3)^2+2*2/3-(2/3)^2)`

Excel returned 1

If I changed the order of the components of the formula to:

`=+(2*2/3-(1/3)^2-(2/3)^2)`

Excel returns 7/9

I checked both in WolframAlpha

[Formula 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%3D%2B%28-%281%2F3%29%5E2%2B22%2F3-%282%2F3%29%5E2%29)

[Formula 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%3D%2B%282*2%2F3-%281%2F3%29%5E2-%282%2F3%29%5E2%29)

and both times I got 7/9

What's wrong with Excel?

Comment: Instead of starting with the premise "why is excel not doing math properly" I would have started with the premise "what did I not do properly..." or in this case, "what part of my formula was ambiguously interpreted by excel". This would have led me to rewrite the equation more explicitly by adding parentheses around `(1/3)^2` or completely `=-((1/3)^2)+(2*2/3)-((2/3)^2)`. This rewrite is in line with the solution below.

Comment: https://www.keynotesupport.com/excel-basics/excel-math-formulas.shtml This formula may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -(1/3) is taking precedence over the ^2, so you square -0.33333.  Negation takes precedence over exponent.

In the second case, the - sign is not negation, but subtraction, and exponents have precedence over subtraction.

From [The Order of Operator Precedence in Excel Formulas](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/the-order-of-operator-precedence-in-excel-formulas/)

- Evaluate items in parentheses.
- Evaluate ranges (:).
- Evaluate intersections (spaces).
- Evaluate unions (,).
- Perform negation (-).
- Convert percentages (%).
- Perform exponentiation (^).
- Perform multiplication (*) and division (/), which are of equal precedence.
- Perform addition (+) and subtraction (-), which are of equal precedence.
- Evaluate text operators (&).
- Perform comparisons (=, <>, <=, >=).

---

From [Wolfram Precedence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Precedence.html):

- Parenthesization,
- Factorial,
- Exponentiation,
- Multiplication and division,
- Addition and subtraction.

> For more complex operations, the order of operations depends on the system.

Wolfram doesn't directly have negation, so interprets the first - as a subtraction.

You are dealing with the idiosynchrancies of the software.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think this order is helpful at all. If Wolfram doesn't use it is for a good reason.

Comment: The brackets group the 1/3, so then the minus has to be negation because it is at the front of the equation.  You are dealing with the idiosyncrasies of the software.

Comment: @jpcgandre You can just as easily say that if Excel does use it, it is for a good reason.